# SSD not showing up at all

Tags: laptop, ssd, bios, windows-10

**Context :** I had a laptop with one HDD and one SSD (Crucial m500 - 128Go) inside but the computer doesn't start anymore so I bought a new laptop (MSI Ge60 2QF) with an mSata slot for my SSD and I want now to insert my old SSD inside my new laptop.

So I've opened my laptop, found where I should put my SSD, plugged it and screw it (it doesn't need something else at this point?)

I had already installed Windows 10 on the HDD so I boot up my computer, went into Disk Management but my SSD doesn't show up. I tried "Rescan for disk", didn't change anything.

I tried Diskpart to list all the disks, it didn't show up neither.

So I went in the Bios, and it does not show up in the Boot order menu.

Screenshot of my Disk Management:

[image]

Screenshot of Diskpart:

[image]

Any suggestion how could I see my SSD in this laptop?